# Count number of times matching string appears in another column (similar to Excel COUNTIF)

Tags: qgis, sql, string

Which function can I use to count the number of times a string for a row in column `"LeaseName"` matches another row's string for `"LeaseName"`?

For example, Row 1 is `'HADLEY #9'` and I want to know the total number of times `'HADLEY #9'` appears in the table for column LeaseName.

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried by so far ? I assume that this question was already been asked and answered. Check @BERA’s profile two months ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First solution using virtual column and field calculator**

Open the attribute table of your layer and click on field calculator icon.
Enter the following expression:

```
count("your_column", "your_column")
```

[image]

If you close and reopen the table the values will be refreshed.

**Second solution to generate a temporary table with unique values and count.**

In table manager open virtual layers (if your data are not in PostGIS/SptiaLite or GeoPackage) and insert an SQL query on the query tab:

```
select your_column, count(*) from your_layer
group by your_column
order by your_column
```

[image]

You will get a new layer which can be joined to the original layer by *your_column*

Answer (score 5):

You can use this expression in field calculator:

```
  array_count( array_agg( "fieldnamecontainingstrings",group_by:="fieldnamecontainingstrings"),"fieldnamecontainingstrings")
```

Comment: Thank you MrXsquared. How would this be done in QGIS where array_count isn't a valid function?

Comment: @AdamC It is available since 3.4 (It is not in 3.4.3 but it is in 3.4.12, so it was introduced somewhere inbetween). Was searching for detailed informations in QGIS changelogs but couldnt find it. So if you are using an earlier version, you can not use this function. However, I think Zoltans solution should work in earlier versions as well.

Comment: @MrXsquared array_count was introduced in QGIS 3.20: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-extended-array-expression-functions
Probably your were using the arrayPlus plugin.